# Bootstrap 4 flexbox navigation with centered logo and items either side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to create a simple bootstrap 4 navigation navbar with my logo centered and a fontawesome menu icon aligned to left and a button aligned to the right.

In my code I have created 3 columns (5, 2 and 5). It works fine if I remove the nav part, but within the nav, it collapses and doesn't take up the full width.  I've read that it is because bootstrap 4 uses flex.     I have tried adding the class w-100 to the row, which nearly works, but it then has a small padding on the right of the navigation which causes the logo to not be exactly centered.

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 text-left bg-warning">
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fas fa-bars text-primary pointer" style="font-size: 28px;" ></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 bg-success text-center">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5 text-right bg-info">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work using flex?  I want to be able to possibly add another button or icon in the right column as well, but still have the logo exactly in the center of the screen.

************* UPDATE **************

I have now got it to work using flex, but I have had to add the style such as "flex: 1 0 40%;" to each of the 3 divs, 40% to the left and right div and 20% to the middle/logo div.  The code doesn't look ideal but it does work.

```
<nav class="navbar bg-light">
    <div class="d-flex w-100">
        <div class="my-auto" style="flex: 1 0 40%;">
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" class="" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fas fa-bars text-primary pointer" style="font-size: 28px;" ></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center" style="flex: 1 0 20%;">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand m-0">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="my-auto text-right" style="flex: 1 0 40%;">
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-watermelon" href="#" role="button">Sign Up</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.navbar` class adds `padding: .5rem 1rem;` style rule to the nav element. The "Logo" text is not centered, because of the `.navbar-brand class`, that adds `margin-right: 1rem;`  Adding content to a column does not change the size of it.
Add these classes to the elements:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-dark pr-0 pl-0">
...
   <a href="/" class="navbar-brand m-0">Logo</a>
...
</nav>
```

The class `pl-0` and `pr-0` will set the left and right paddings to 0, while `m-0` will remove all margins.

Here is a very nice [cheat-sheat for bootstrap 4](https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 0):

THis is it:

```
  <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar bg-dark">
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" class="navbar-toggler" data- 
            target="#exampleModal"><i
            class="fas fa-bars text-primary pointer btn btn-warning" style="font- 
            size: 28px;"></i></a>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand btn btn-success">Logo</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="#" role="button">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
```

check:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/gn89rj5p/